# Set a fixed margin between list component

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, listitem

I'm using a Material UI list component in my code.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<List>
    <ListItem button>
      <ListItemText
        disableTypography
        primary={<Typography>Hello</Typography>}
      />
      <p>John</p>
      <DraftsIcon />
    </ListItem>
  </List>
```

Here is the screenshot of the result:
[image]

How can I set a fixed distance between "Hello" and "John"?

and avoid the following case:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "fixed margin"? What exactly is your desired look?

Comment: I meant fixed distance, for instance can I add 'margin-right: 5px' on Hello. So that distance between Hello and John always stays 5px even if I reduce size of screen

Comment: Use StackBlitz to create the output so that others can debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// just add minWidth in button 

     <List>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText
            style={{minWidth:"50px" }}
            disableTypography
            primary={<Typography>Hello</Typography>}
          />
          <p>John</p>
          <DraftsIcon />
        </ListItem>
      </List>
```

you can also do something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import { IconButton, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import DraftsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Drafts";

export default function FlexGrow() {
  return (
      <Box display="flex" p={1} >
        <Box p={1} flexGrow={1} >
        <Typography variant="button" display="block" gutterBottom>
          Hello
        </Typography>
        </Box>
        <Box p={1} >
        <Typography variant="button" display="block" gutterBottom>
          John
        </Typography>
        </Box>
      <IconButton color="inherit" style={{marginTop :"-10px"}}>
        <DraftsIcon/>
        </IconButton>
      </Box>
  );
}
```